# How to restrict level crossings in route?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I want to evaluate if it is useful to bypass a level crossing through a nearby tunnel or overpass when the LC is closed or if it is worth waiting.
I want to use the OSM data for realistic scenarios and calculate the most time efficient route for closed and opened LC.
Is it possible to solve this problem with pgRouting?
Or can you give me some hints where to start?

Answer (score 1):

In 2012 a "time dependent shortest path" algorithm (TDSP) was implemented as a Google Summer of Code project: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Time-dependent---Dynamic-Shortest-Path

This algorithm might be what you are looking for, but it was not added to pgRouting 2.0, so it would require some effort or funding to integrate it.